# VirtualBox suddenly gives "Linux Kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded ..."

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I've been running Ubuntu 16.04 with VirtualBox 5.1.18 for months to run Windows 10 in a VM.  Today starting the Win10 VM gives the above error message and says to

```
Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

    '/sbin/vboxconfig'

    as root.
```

Doing that fails.  The log file is full of compile errors.

Does anyone know what caused VirtualBox to suddenly fail and what the solution is?

[image: Error Dialog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing VirtualBox 5.1 and installing version 5.2.  My VM started up properly after upgrading with no other steps.